# Generic Entity in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring, generics, jpa

I have a Use Case where I need to persist a Generic Entity. The generic Entity would look like this:

```
public class Terminal<T extends ConductingEquipment> extends ACDCTerminal {
    private ConnectivityNode connectivityNode;
    private PhaseCode phases;
    private T conductingEquipment
}
```

`T` could be one of 38 classes, which for example `extends Conductor`, which by itself `extends ConductingEquipment`. From my point of view, there are several implementations possible, which I can imagine from the Database site:

1. Terminal with 38 fields one for each possible `T`
2. 38 different Terminal Tables (one for each `T`)
3. A mapping table which tells JPA in which `T`-table to look for the correct ConductingEquipment. This would mean `conductingEquipment` is a semi foreign key for 38 different tables

My questions are:

1. Which solution would be the best (or even a completely different)
2. How would the solution be implemented in Spring Data JPA

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding. Object relational mappimgs has some fundamental criticism (object modelling not always has elegant solution in relational DB). Maybe tottaly different storage? Disclaimer: I don't undestand main problem. What kind of application?

Comment: We would prefer ORM, because we have a lot of classes (more than 100). The application is to implement the [CGMES CIM Standard](https://www.entsoe.eu/major-projects/common-information-model-cim/cim-for-grid-models-exchange/standards/Pages/default.aspx). With this we want to persist the data we receive, work with it and return data when needed.

Comment: Why do you feel `Terminal` should be generic? Can't you just make `conductingEquipment` of the base type `ConductingEquipment`?

Comment: No, because then I can't access the fields of the sub-classes. (Which are more important than the ones of the base class) Also, I don't think, that the fields of the sub-classes would be stored in the database.

Comment: The fields of subclasses **will** be stored in the database (see here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance for possible ways to store an inheritance hierarchy using JPA, it should answer most of your questions). How are you planning to query the persistent storage to obtain a reference to a `Terminal<T>` with `T` of a specific type? You will need casting at some point, anyway

Comment: Sorry, I think my comment was misunderstood. I know, that Inheritance works in JPA, what I mean is kind of the second part of your last comment. Casting wouldn't work since I don't know which sub-class to use.